# TRying to get 3 Text vues to be left, centered and right aligned on same row

Tags: android

I'm trying to get 3 TextView on the same line where they are left justified, centered and right justified.  They are all on the left hand side. They are all in a horizontal container.  I'm using layout_gravity to set there potions

code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#fff7f1d2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



   <ImageView           
            android:id="@+id/butMenu"       
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/menu"

        />    

   <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff7f1d2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="left"
               android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:textStyle="bold"
            />    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="center"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
            />    


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="In case of Emergency: Break Glass"
               android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textStyle="bold"
            />    


    </LinearLayout> 

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use gravity instead of layout gravity to position your text. use width=0dp and weight=1 for all 3 to space them evenly

Answer (score 0):

`Gravity` left and right doesn't work for a `horizontal` `LinearLayout` since it already lays them out from left to right. You are better off wrapping them in a `RelativeLayout` and using its properties.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff7f1d2">
   <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="left"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>    
   <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"    <!-- This property -->
        android:textStyle="bold"/>    

   <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="In case of Emergency: Break Glass"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  <!-- And this property -->
        android:textStyle="bold" />    

</RelativeLayout>
```

The first `TextView` will be aligned to the right by default.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the LinearLayout's width set to `fill_parent`, you can do this an easier way:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff7f1d2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"a
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="left"
        android:textStyle="bold" /> 

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="center"
        android:textStyle="bold" />    

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="In case of Emergency: Break Glass"
        android:textStyle="bold" />    

</LinearLayout>
```

The difference here is the `android:layout_weight` attribute and since all the siblings have the same weight each `TextView` will take up 33% of the available width.